# Export of PNG sequence does not match video framerate

Tags: export

I have an image sequence (PNG) of a motion capture session, that I export from Blender that should match the video.

For some reason however the sequence won't match the video - I double-checked - I export (and import into Premiere) at the same FPS as the original video.

Comment: Does the export *Frame Rate* you can find in the *Render tab* in the *Dimensions* panel match the original video framerate? Could you post some values?

Comment: Is your blender scene set to the same framerate as premiere's? Is premiere interpreting the footage correctly (clip->Modify->Interpret footage)?

Comment: @Carlo : Yes - it's 25fps export in blender & 25fps in premiere